# How to apply css in JSP?

Tags: css, jsp

```
 #section>.snb .tit{position:relative;}
    #section>.snb .tit h1{color:#2765b1;font-size:20px;text-indent:25px;}
```

I am not sure how to apply the css code above to jsp page. It looks different from the basic css with

```
body { 
    background: #00ff00 url("smiley.gif") no-repeat fixed center; 
}
```

kind format.

Comment: you want to apply this background in your css right

Comment: yes!  that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply like this :

```html
<html>
<head>
<style> 
 #section>.snb .tit{position:relative;}
    #section>.snb .tit h1{color:#2765b1;font-size:20px;text-indent:25px;}

</style>
</head>
<body>



<div id="section">
<div class="snb">
<div class="tit">
<h1>test text</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Please refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) it will help you to understand css selectors. 
In

```
#section>.snb .tit h1{color:#2765b1;font-size:20px;text-indent:25px;}
```

it look for h1 tag in element with 'tit' class inside all element's with class value as 'snb' in element with id 'section'.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have a quick one more question. So > basically stands for all elements class and # is for id?

Comment: > for all elements that are on right of operator in element on leftside of operator, # for id and .for class